# BufferedReader input to doubly linked list

Tags: java, bufferedreader, doubly-linked-list

I am doing a project for Data Structures. I need to have the user input Strings into a doubly linked list using bufferedReader, where -1 terminates the stream and displays the list. Here is what I have so far. Every input I enter is throwing an exception and closing the Stream. Where am I going wrong?

```
public class Main {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int count;
    String inputString;
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
    DoublyLinkedList list = new DoublyLinkedList();//does this go in the loop?

    while ((inputString = in.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a String, then press enter.");

        if (inputString.equals(-1) {
          displayList();
        } else {
          list.insertFirst(inputString);
        } 

    count++
    in.close();
}
   /**
 *
 */
public static void displayList() 
    {
    Node first = null;
    Node node = first;

        while(node != null){

            node.displayNode();

            System.out.println("Next Link: " + node.next);

            node = node.next;

            System.out.println();

        }

    }  

}
```

Node Class:

```
public class Node {

public String dData; // data item
public Node next; // next node in list
public Node previous; // previous node in list


/**
 *
 * @param d
 */
public Node(String d) // constructor
    { 
dData = d; 
    }

public void displayNode() // display this link
    {
System.out.print(dData + " ");
    } 
}// end class Node
```

Doubly-linked-list Class:

```
    public class DoublyLinkedList {

    public Node first; // ref to first item

    /**
     *
     */
    public Node last; // ref to last item


    public DoublyLinkedList() // constructor
    {
        first = null; // no items on list yet
        last = null;
    }


    public boolean isEmpty() // true if no links
    {
        return first == null;
    }


    public void insertFirst(String dd) // insert at front of list
    {
        Node newNode = new Node(dd); // make new link

        if (isEmpty()) // if empty list,
        {
            last = newNode; // newLink <-- last
        } else {
            first.previous = newNode; // newLink <-- old first
        }
        newNode.next = first; // newLink --> old first
        first = newNode; // first --> newLink
    }


    public void insertLast(String dd) // insert at end of list
    {
        Node newNode = new Node(dd); // make new link
        if (isEmpty()) // if empty list,
        {
            first = newNode; // first --> newLink
        } else {
            last.next = newNode; // old last --> newLink
            newNode.previous = last; // old last <-- newLink
        }
        last = newNode; // newLink <-- last
    }


    public Node deleteFirst() // delete first link
    { // (assumes non-empty list)
        Node temp = first;
        if (first.next == null) // if only one item
        {
            last = null; // null <-- last
        } else {
            first.next.previous = null; // null <-- old next
        }
        first = first.next; // first --> old next
        return temp;
    }

    public Node deleteLast() // delete last link
    { // (assumes non-empty list)
        Node temp = last;
        if (first.next == null) // if only one item
        {
            first = null; // first --> null
        } else {
            last.previous.next = null; // old previous --> null
        }
        last = last.previous; // old previous <-- last
        return temp;
    }

// insert dd just after key

    public boolean insertAfter(String key, String dd) { // (assumes non-empty list)
        Node current = first; // start at beginning
        while (!current.dData.equals(key)) // until match is found,
        {
            current = current.next; // move to next link
            if (current == null) {
                return false; // didn’t find it
            }
        }
        Node newNode = new Node(dd); // make new link

        if (current == last) // if last link,
        {
            newNode.next = null; // newLink --> null
            last = newNode; // newLink <-- last
        } else // not last link,
        {
            newNode.next = current.next; // newLink --> old next
// newLink <-- old next
            current.next.previous = newNode;
        }
        newNode.previous = current; // old current <-- newLink
        current.next = newNode; // old current --> newLink
        return true; // found it, did insertion
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param key
     * @return
     */
    public Node deleteKey(String key) // delete item w/ given key
    { // (assumes non-empty list)
        Node current = first; // start at beginning

        while (!current.dData.equals(key)) // until match is found,
        {
            current = current.next; // move to next link
            if (current == null) {
                return null; // didn’t find it
            }
        }
        if (current == first) // found it; first item?
        {
            first = current.next; // first --> old next
        } else // not first
        // old previous --> old next
        {
            current.previous.next = current.next;
        }

        if (current == last) // last item?
        {
            last = current.previous; // old previous <-- last
        } else // not last
        // old previous <-- old next
        {
            current.next.previous = current.previous;
        }
        return current; // return value
    }


    public void displayForward() {
        System.out.print("List(first-- > last): ");
        Node current = first; // start at beginning
        while (current != null) // until end of list,
        {
            current.displayNode(); // display data
            current = current.next; // move to next link
        }
        System.out.println("");
}

public void displayBackward() {
        System.out.print("List(last-- > first): ");
        Node current = last; // start at end
        while (current != null) // until start of list,
        {
            current.displayNode(); // display data
            current = current.previous; // move to previous link


}
        System.out.println("");
}

} // end class DoublyLinkedList
```

Comment: For starters, this line isn't doing what you think `if (inputString = '-1') {`. That's an assignment, not an equality test. Also, single quotes are typically used to identify single characters, not strings (which use double quotes). As for what to do, you can use `break` to break out of the loop when you read in -1.

Comment: I was playing around with it and forgot to change it back, my bad. This is what I currently have: if (inputString == -1)

Comment: String equality isn't tested using `==` but rather the `.equals()` method on the `String` object. `inputString.equals("-1");` I should point out that this stems to _all_ objects in general, as `==` only tests reference and primitive equality. I used String here because that's the object type that is relevant to the question.

Comment: @texastrosc you have a semi-colon missing and an unclosed method body.

Comment: @RyanJ I feel like such an idiot, I don't know how I missed that, thank you

I updated the post and the code, I'm running into a much bigger error now.

Comment: **Why** are you doing `in.close()` inside the while-loop?

Comment: @texastrosch well, based on those updates, you have a couple issues still. 1) you are missing a closing curly brace somewhere in your posted code, which is giving us misleading info. 2) Checking `String` equality with an `Integer` argument isn't going to work either. 3) Suppose you did get that to work, once you display the list you don't break out of the loop. Lastly, mind sharing the exception(s) you're getting and posting the stack trace? You're leaving a lot out.

Comment: @RyanJ he’s closing the stream inside the loop.

Comment: @RishavKundu with a curly brace missing I'm not assuming anything. That code won't compile, and if he's getting exceptions then he's got a different version. If that is indeed the case, then posting the exception and stack trace will verify that.

Comment: @RishavKundu I placed that wrong, easy fix. It is still not displaying the list when I type in -1 (if it is even creating a list.)

Comment: `Every input I enter is throwing an exception` - and the exception is...?

Comment: @texastrosch, yeah you haven’t even called displayList.

Comment: Please post the *actual* code. Not what you think it does. The difference between what you think it does and what it really is *is* the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, you had a bunch of mistakes,

1. Missing out a brace.
2. Closing the stream inside the loop. (How are you going to read input in the next iteration?)
3. `displayList` did not take any arguments (How will print the `LinkedList` if it doesn’t have any references to it?
4. Last but not the least, you didn’t even call displayList.

The `Node` and `LinkedList` classes are fine. I also made some other minor changes.

```
import java.io.*;

class Main {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 */

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    int count = 0;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    DoublyLinkedList list = new DoublyLinkedList();//does this go in the loop?
    System.out.println("Enter a String, then press enter.");
    String inputString = br.readLine();
    while ((inputString != null) )
    {
        if (inputString.equals("-1")) 
        {
          break;
        } 
        else 
        {
          list.insertFirst(inputString);
        } 
       inputString =br.readLine();
       count++;
  }

  displayList(list);
  br.close();
}

public static void displayList(DoublyLinkedList d) 
    {

    Node node = d.first;

        while(node != null)
        {

            node.displayNode();

            //System.out.println("Next Link: " + node.next);

            node = node.next;

            System.out.println();

        }

    }  

}
```

Comment: That definitely fixed a lot of things, but when I print the list I get "project_3.Node@659e0bfd" in between the "next link: " and node.next

Comment: Yes, because you’re printing `node.next` which is a memory hash. You don’t want that? Just remove that line.

Answer (score 0):

Your while should look like this:

```
System.out.println("Enter a String, then press enter.");
while (!(inputString = in.readLine()).equals("-1")) {
    if (in.readLine().equals("")) { // filter empty lines, user probably hit enter twice
        continue;
    }
    // add inputString to the list
    System.out.println("Enter a String, then press enter.");
}
// print list
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make 2 changes:

1. Change:

   ```
   inputString.equals(-1)  // A String cannot be equal to an integer.
   ```

   to

   ```
   inputString.equals("-1")
   ```
2. To break out of the loop if user enters `-1`, add a `break;` statement after `displayList()`.

#### Then you asked

```
 DoublyLinkedList list = new DoublyLinkedList();//does this go in the loop?
```

#### Answer:

No. It doesn't enter a loop. Why do you think it does? It just calls the constructor of `class DoublyLinkedList` whici initializes `first` and `last` equal to `null`